# Unity3D, не отрисовывается форма

Tags: unity3d, форма

Помогите пожалуйста новичку разобраться, почему не работает код:

(Ошибок компиляции нет, скрипт висит на персонаже с которого есть управление, все 5 обьектов(и все их поля) в инспекторе заполнены. Задумывалось как форма с пятью кнопками, при нажатии на которых воспроизводится звук. И я знаю что сделано по нубски, но это проба пера, заработает - перепишу по человечески.)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GUI_Window : MonoBehaviour {
    public AudioSource audio;
    public objSound obj1;
    public objSound obj2;
    public objSound obj3;
    public objSound obj4;
    public objSound obj5;

public Rect windowSize = new Rect(15,15,250,50);

void Start () {
        audio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }
    private void onGUI(){
        windowSize = GUI.Window(0,windowSize,myWindow,"1");}

    private void myWindow(int id){
    if (GUI.Button(new Rect(0,0,50,50),obj1.picture)){
             AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(obj1.sound, this.transform.position);
    }
    if (GUI.Button(new Rect(50,0,50,50),obj2.picture)){
        AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(obj2.sound, this.transform.position);}
    if (GUI.Button(new Rect(100,0,50,50),obj3.picture)){
        AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(obj3.sound, this.transform.position);}
    if (GUI.Button(new Rect(150,0,50,50),obj4.picture)){
        AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(obj4.sound, this.transform.position);}
    if (GUI.Button(new Rect(200,0,50,50),obj5.picture)){
        AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(obj5.sound, this.transform.position);}
GUI.DragWindow();
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обратите внимание на то, что метод [OnGUI()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnGUI.html) является "особенным" в Unity и вызывается не напрямую а через внутренние вызовы по имени, и в вашем коде название этого метода написано неправильно (с маленькой буквы).

Comment: Спасибо, всё заработало.